# Crystal report Formula Error String is required

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I am working in crystal reports and I have created two parameters named `startDate` and `endDate` and when I go to Formula selection and I write the code and save it I got an error message "string is required"
the code is:

`if {Employees.DateField} >={?startDatePF} and {Employees.DateField}<={?endDate} then true`

Please tell me how can I resolve this error.

```
Public Sub GetReport()
  Dim rpt As New CrystalReport1
  rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\CrystalReport1.rpt")
  Dim pfield As New ParameterField
  Dim pfields As New ParameterFields
  Dim pdescrete As New ParameterDiscreteValue
  Dim pfield1 As New ParameterField
  Dim pfields1 As New ParameterFields
End Sub
```

Comment: You want us to take the time, look at your problem and help you - so please try to make some effort in asking your question.

Comment: sounds like your parameters are not set to date types

Comment: You are returing a boolean in a formula... instead try to return string